# OneSignal Android not launching app with custom onNotificationOpened handler

Tags: java, android, onesignal

I am attempting to migrate an app from Parse to OneSignal. Things have been running fairly smooth except for one issue. If the app has not already been started, clicking (opening) the notification does not launch the app and bring it to the foreground.

I am using a custom `onNotificationOpenedHandler`:

Main Activity, onCreate

```
// Init OneSignal
        OneSignal.startInit(this).setNotificationOpenedHandler(new NotificationOpenHandler()).init();
```

`NotificationOpenedHandler`, also in the launcher Main Activity:

```
class NotificationOpenHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler {
        // This fires when a notification is opened by tapping on it.
        @Override
        public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenResult result) {
            JSONObject data = result.notification.payload.additionalData;

            String stationName = data.optString("stationName");
            String timestamp = data.optString("timestamp");
            String filename = data.optString("filename");
            String url = getString(R.string.callResourceUrl) + filename;

            Log.d("APP", "Notification clicked");

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CallActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("stationName", stationName);
            intent.putExtra("time", timestamp);
            intent.putExtra("url", url);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Here is my Android Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.opheliadesign.tevfd">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <application
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:logo="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Tevfd">
        <activity android:name="com.example.app.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".CallActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_call"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.app.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationOpened.DEFAULT" android:value="DISABLE" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**
Previously, using Parse, I utilized a BroadcastReceiver with a PendingIntent. It seems a bit unclear how to accomplish this with OneSignal as so much seems to be configured automatically.

If I remove the custom Intent, the application comes to the foreground.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you post error logs

Comment: There are none to post. When tapping the notification nothing happens if the app is not running. When you open the app, the intent fires.

Comment: Inside manifest, u defined  `android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
`, this could possibly be the culprit. CallActivity can now be only launched in context of `MainActivity`.